Spring Boot application in Docker failing to connect to MySQL database in another container
I'd appreciate some assistance with my Docker Compose setup. I'm trying to connect a Spring Boot application running in one container to a MySQL database in another container, but the connection seems to be failing.
Here's my current setup:
I'm using Docker Compose to define my services.
One service is for the Spring Boot application.
The other service is for the MySQL database (mysql:latest).
Both services are connected to the same network defined in docker-compose.yml.
I've tried two approaches to connect the Spring application to the database:
Using service discovery and network aliases:
The Spring application configuration uses jdbc:mysql://database:3306/my_db for the connection URL (database being the service name for the MySQL container). this was written in the Dockerfile as an argument for the start of the spring server.
Here are some additional details that might be helpful:
I've verified that mysql container is running and is healthy within Docker.
I've checked the network configuration in docker-compose.yml to ensure they are connected to the same network.
The MySQL service has a health check configured using mysqladmin ping to verify its availability.
What could be causing the connection issue between my Spring application and the MySQL database container? Any suggestions or troubleshooting steps would be greatly appreciated.
Here's a relevant snippet from my Dockerfile file (excluding sensitive information):
FROM openjdk:21-jdk

# Set the working directory inside the container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the compiled JAR file into the container
COPY out/artifacts/jar-with-dependencies.jar /app/your-spring-server.jar

# Command to run the Spring server
CMD ["java", "-jar", "/app/your-spring-server.jar", "--spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://10.5.0.5:3307/my_db"]
# I also tried this
# CMD ["java", "-jar", "/app/your-spring-server.jar", "--spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://container_db:3307/my_db"]

Here's a relevant snippet from my docker-compose.yml file (excluding sensitive information):
services:
  database:
    image: mysql:latest
    container_name: container_db
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: my_db
    ports:
        - "3307:3306"
    healthcheck:
        test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin" ,"ping", "-h", "localhost", "-u root", "-proot"]
        interval: 10s
        timeout: 5s
        retries: 3
    networks:
        docker_network:
          aliases:
            - container_db
          ipv4_address: 10.5.0.5

  spring_server:
    image: spring-app-img
    container_name: spring_server
    ports:
      - "8089:8088"
    depends_on:
        database:
            condition: service_healthy
    networks:
      docker_network:
        aliases:
          - spring_server
        ipv4_address: 10.5.0.6

networks:
  docker_network:
    driver: bridge
    name: my_network
    ipam:
        config:
            - subnet: 10.5.0.0/16
              gateway: 10.5.0.1


How exactly are you specifying the database configuration?  What is the exact error you're getting?

(You should be able to simplify this by deleting all of the networks: blocks.  Compose will automatically create a network for you named default, and attach containers to it.  You should never need to know or manually specify the container-private IP addresses.  You can also remove container_name:.  Between these, you'd remove fully half of that Compose file.)

@DavidMaze The error I get is: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure. You can see in the Dockerfile the entrypoint of the spring app has another parameter which is the database connection url

The standard MySQL port is 3306, and you need to use that port for connections between containers.  ports: aren't used or required in this case.  Use the Compose service name database in place of the IP address.

Docker Compose + Spring Boot + Postgres connection also has some discussion of this setup.

@DavidMaze so i over-complicated the docker-compose. I made the modification you mentioned and know it seems to work. But I still don`t understand what was my problem. From my host machine I could access the exposed port 3037 of the mysql container.

Connections between containers are different from connections from the host system, and ports: aren't used there.  You always need to use the standard port number, for MySQL 3306, if you're connecting to another container.
